# how to update a sql database that has a dropdown list in php

Tags: php, sql, database, drop-down-menu, wampserver

I have a html form for user to submit their inquiry. after submitting the form, the data will go to php file and then it will connect to the database. I can do that.

the problem is, for admin view, it will have a dropdown list (approved/not approved) for admin to validate the data. how to update the database? I managed to do the dropdown, but when I clicked the save button, the database didn't update anything.

this is form.html which the user see, (nothing wrong here)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>data</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#13b4ff">

    <div id="header" style="background-color: #4169E1;"><hr>

    <form class="form" action="submit.php" method="post" name="form" >

    <ul>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Nama Pemohon:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="jawatan">Jawatan:</label>
        <input type="text" name="jawatan" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="unit">Unit/Jabatan/Bahagian:</label>
        <input type="text" name="unit" required />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="kementerian">Kementerian/Institusi/Agensi:</label>
        <input type="text" name="kementerian" required />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="telefon">No. Telefon:</label>
        <input type="number" name="telefon" placeholder="eg: 012-345-6789" required />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="faks">No. Faks:</label>
        <input type="number" name="faks" placeholder="eg: 03-12345678" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="name@something.com" required />
    <span class="form_hint">proper format<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script></span>
</li>
    <li>
        <label for="data">Data/Laporan Yang Dipohon:</label>
        <input type="text" name="data" required/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="tujuan">Tujuan:</label>
        <input type="text" name="tujuan" required/>
    </li>
    <li>
    <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </li> 
    </ul>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the submit.php that connects to the database, (nothing wrong here too)

```
<?php

//debug mode
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

//to show some error is smthng went wrong
$errors = array();

function connect(){
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "" );
    $db = mysql_select_db('permohonan_data', $connection);

if (!$connection || !$db){
    return false;
    }
else{
    return true;
    }
}

//will run if user did submit the form
if (!empty($_POST)){

//connect sql server:
if (!connect()){
    $errors[] = "Can't establish link to MySql server";
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $jawatan = $_POST['jawatan'];
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
    $kementerian = $_POST['kementerian'];
    $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
    $faks = $_POST['faks'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $tujuan = $_POST['tujuan'];

//no error til here
if (empty($error)){

//prevent SQL injection
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);    
$jawatan = mysql_real_escape_string($jawatan);
$unit = mysql_real_escape_string($unit);
$kementerian = mysql_real_escape_string($kementerian);
$telefon = mysql_real_escape_string($telefon);
$faks = mysql_real_escape_string($faks);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
$tujuan = mysql_real_escape_string($tujuan);

}

//try insert value
$query = "INSERT INTO pemohon
    (name,jawatan,unit,kementerian,telefon,faks,email,data,tujuan)
    VALUES ('$name', '$jawatan', '$unit', '$kementerian', '$telefon', '$faks', '$email', '$data', '$tujuan')";

//try
if (!mysql_query($query)){
    //
    //die(mysql_error());
    $errors[] = "Can't insert the values";
    }
else {
    //on success
    header("Location:thankyou.php");
    exit();

}

}   

?>
```

this is the admin.php for the admin used only. (here's the problem)

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['pswd']))
{
        header("location:form.html");
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylenav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylestable.css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#13b4ff">

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="admin.php">HOME</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="admin/new.php">NEW&nbsp;USER</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="#">Pengesah</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="#">Penyedia</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="#">UPDATE</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<table id='display'>
<col span="1" class="wide1">
<col span="1" class="wide3">
<col span="1" class="wide3">
<col span="1" class="wide4">
<col span="1" class="wide4">
<col span="1" class="wide2">
<col span="1" class="wide3">
<col span="1" class="wide3">
<col span="1" class="wide5">

    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAMA PEMOHON</th>
        <th>UNIT/JABATAN/&nbsp;<br>BAHAGIAN</th>
        <th>NO.TELEFON</th>
        <th>NO.FAKS</th>
        <th>E-MAIL</th>
        <th>DATA/LAPORAN YANG DIPOHON</th>
        <th>TUJUAN</th>
        <th>TINDAKAN</th>
    </tr>

<tbody>
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$connect){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("permohonan_data");
    $option = '';
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pemohon ORDER BY id DESC");

    $option .='<select>';
    $count=mysql_num_rows($results);
    {
    $tindakan = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['tindakan']));

$_query = "UPDATE permohonan_data SET pemohon = '$tindakan' WHERE id = $id";

    if($result_query = mysql_query($_query))
    {
        $status_query= "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        $status_query= "Failed";
    }
}

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "<a href='full_details.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['id']."</a>" ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['unit']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['telefon']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['faks']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['data']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['tujuan']?></td>
        <td><select>
        <option <?php if( $row['tindakan'] == '-'){ echo "selected";}?> >-</option>
        <option <?php if( $row['tindakan'] == 'app'){ echo "selected";}?> >APPROVED</option>
        <option <?php if( $row['tindakan'] == 'notapp'){ echo "selected";}?> >NOT APPROVED</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
    $option .='</select>';
?>

</tbody>
</table>
<input type='submit' value='Save'>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

save button didn't work.

Comment: Your save button doesn't work, because it isn't named: `<input type='submit' value='Save'>` due to your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` change it to this `<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save'>` and it should theoretically work, IF the rest of your code checks out. I'm sure someone's gonna see this and make it as an answer, and so be it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, point taken. I change the code, but the save button still doesn't work. and it didn't give any error too.

Comment: You're welcome. That's why I said "IF" the rest of your code checks out. Another thing I noticed now, is this line `SET pemohon = tindakan = '".$tindakan."'` that doesn't seem right to me, having those two equal signs like that. I'd double-check that. You may need a `WHERE column='something'` or that this line `SET pemohon = tindakan = '".$tindakan."'` should only be `SET pemohon = '".$tindakan."'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I change that into this, `"UPDATE permohonan_data SET pemohon = '$_tindakan' WHERE id = $_id";`. is this valid? *the update still doesnt work though*

Comment: The only other thing I can tell without having to set up a whole DB/table, is this `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` --- I suspect that anything outside of it (on top and bottom) of that conditional statement, will not take effect. Either get rid of it (to test) or place it up higher.

Comment: @Fred-ii- get rid of it and this error comes out, `Undefined index: tindakan ... on line 68` and  `Undefined variable: id ... line 70`

Comment: `tindakan` is undefined because there is no POST variable called `$tindakan=$_POST['tindakan'];` you're only "trying" to define it with `$tindakan = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['tindakan']));` which doesn't count. You'd need a form input (if one is supposed to be taken from the form) to the affect of (if it's a text-based input) `<input type="text" name="tindakan">`

Answer (score 0):

OK, Fred, I'll bite.  ;)  Your save button doesn't work, because it isn't named: 
   `<input type='submit' value='Save'>`
due to your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` change it to this
   `<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save'>`
and it should theoretically work, IF the rest of your code checks out.

Comment: Why did you copy and paste Fred's comment?

Comment: I was simply fulfilling his prophecy.  I guess an equally valid question is, "Why did Fred post an answer in a comment?"

Comment: And that is why I said "IF" the rest of the OP's code checks out, which seems NOT to be checking out. ;-) There's usually other problems that arise from questions like these, but hey... was worth a shot, right? @zylstra